# UIView animation happens in the wrong direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

For some reason my `UIImageView` animates to its start position, from its end position. I can’t work out why but have a feeling it’s something to do with using constraints (I use constraints on all `UIView`s throughout my app).

My animation should animate `logoImageView` off the top of the screen.

Here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.logoImageView.center));

[self.logoImageView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                 animations:^{
                     [self.logoImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.logoImageView.frame),
                                                               CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) + CGRectGetHeight(self.logoImageView.frame))];

                     [self.logoImageView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.logoImageView.center));

                     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Play" sender:nil];
                 }];
```

Here is my log of positions:

```
2014-09-05 18:08:56.673 Cups[2142:89629] {160, 111.5}
2014-09-05 18:09:01.250 Cups[2142:89629] {160, 645}
```

But the animation plays the other way round. Any ideas?

Comment: I should also say I’ve tried calling `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` on `self.view` too with the same outcome

Comment: I think the right approach is to animate the constraints rather than positioning or frames.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with the fact that you're calling `-updateLayoutConstraints` without actually updating constraints.

A better approach would be to animate the constraints rather than setting the position and frames of your views. A good trick to remember is that you can create outlets in your XIB to your constraints.

Let's assume you have an `NSLayoutConstraint` called `logoImageViewTopConstraint` set up as an IBOutlet in your view controller which sets the top of the `logoImageView` to it's superview's top layout guide. At design time set that constraint's constant to 100 or so (moving it down 100 points from the top of the view). Then with that constraint you could do something like this for your animation:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
self.logoImageViewTopConstraint.constant = 0;   // moves image view back to the top
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];    
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];             // interpolates animation from changes to constraints
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // done
}];
```

If you get it working just play with the constants of the constraints until you get the exact effect that you want.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f
                 animations:^
                 {
                     [self.logoImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.logoImageView.frame),
                                                           -(CGRectGetHeight(self.logoImageView.frame)/2)];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) 
                 {
                     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Play" sender:nil];
                 }];
```

1. animate to y center = -(logoHeight/2).  This is "off the top of the screen" in iOS coordinates
2. don't call updateConstraints in animation block

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a CABasicAnimation running on the layer of the UIView was interrupting the UIView animation. Thanks for suggestions